# Object bracket notation in definition of an Object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, notation, object-literal

```
var events = {
                addEvent: function(element, type, fn, capture){
                     element.addEventListener(type, fn, capture);
                },
                removeEvent: function(){
                     element.removeEventListener(type, fn, capture);
                }
           }
```

I'm loking for something like this in object literal definition to reduce the code
the event Object is just an example

```
           var events = {
                            [action + "Event"]: function(element, type, fn, capture){
                                  element[action + "eventListener"](type, fn, capture);
                        }
                }
           }
```

I know there are other options like

```
element.events.add(....) , element.events.remove(....)
```

or this option

```
element.events("add", type, fn, capture) / element.events("remove", type, fn, capture)
```

Comment: That's not possible in JavaScript. In an object initializer, the property names must be constants.

Comment: which aproach is the best one ?

Comment: You can add properties with dynamically-constructed names with separate assignment statements and the `[ ]` operator.

Comment: can u give me an example or a link

Comment: I'll add an answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Property names in object initializers must be constants. You can however add properties to an object and create names dynamically:

```
var events = {
            addEvent: function(element, type, fn, capture){
                 element.addEventListener(type, fn, capture);
            },
            removeEvent: function(){
                 element.removeEventListener(type, fn, capture);
            }
       };

events[action + "Event"] = function() { /* ... */ };
```

Comment: u mean first create an empty object and then with bracket notation define a function ?

Comment: @CameronA yes - you can add all the properties you want after the object is created. However, in the object initializer itself, the property names must be constants.

Comment: EcmaScript 6 has something called Computed Property Name and it is exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: @CameronA yes that's true! In ES6 things are more flexible.